# Build conda package cryptography:37.0.2 with python 3.8.0

Tags: python, conda, pypi, conda-forge

I am attempting to build conda package for [cryptogaphy](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/37.0.2/):37.0.2 for osx-arm64.
The build fails, if I try to build it with dependecy of python 3.8; the same build is successful, if I use python 3.10. Can anyone help me on how to build the cryptogaphy 37.0.2 library(Conda package) compatible with python 3.8 for osx-arm64 architecture. I am completely blocked, and not sure how to proceed.

I am using the following conda recipe:

```
package:
  name: cryptography
  version: 37.0.2
source:
  url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/e2/89a180c6dc1c3fe33f7f8965da6401cf0b31f440f4e59e9b024b6f54eb0c/cryptography-37.0.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_10_universal2.whl
build:
  number: '0'
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/e2/89a180c6dc1c3fe33f7f8965da6401cf0b31f440f4e59e9b024b6f54eb0c/cryptography-37.0.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_10_universal2.whl

  string: py38_0
requirements:
  build:
    - python 3.8
    - ca-certificates
    - cffi 1.15
    - pycparser 2.21
    - python_abi 3.10
    - openssl 1.1
  run:
    - python 3.8
    - ca-certificates
    - cffi 1.15
    - pycparser 2.21
    - python_abi 3.10
    - openssl 1.1
test:
  imports:
    - cryptography

about:
  description: https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files
  dev_url: https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files
  home: https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files
extra:
  copy_test_source_files: true
  final: true
```

Details on my system:

```
% conda --version
conda 22.11.1
% python --version
Python 3.8.15
% uname -a
Darwin TESTUSER-KPQ05P 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:20:05 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
MacOS Monterey
Version 12.6.1
```

Error message received when running `conda build`
(From my exp the error message doesn't point in the right direction majority of the times.)

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                           

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:
 /Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/conda-bld/work 
  Test:
 /Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/conda-bld/test_tmp 
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test:
source activate  /Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/conda-bld/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold 
  Build:
source activate  /Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/conda-bld/_build_env 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/environ.py", line 796, in get_install_actions
    actions = install_actions(prefix, index, specs, force=True)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/plan.py", line 470, in install_actions
    txn = solver.solve_for_transaction(prune=prune, ignore_pinned=not pinned)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 136, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 179, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 303, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._run_sat(ssc)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 848, in _run_sat
    ssc.solution_precs = ssc.r.solve(tuple(final_environment_specs),
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 1326, in solve
    self.find_conflicts(specs, specs_to_add, history_specs)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 354, in find_conflicts
    raise UnsatisfiableError(bad_deps, strict=strict_channel_priority)
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package pycparser conflicts for:
pycparser=2.21
cffi=1.15 -> pycparser

Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
cffi=1.15 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
pycparser=2.21 -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
python=3.8 -> sqlite[version='>=3.37.1,<4.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
ca-certificates

Package openssl conflicts for:
cffi=1.15 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.5,<4.0a0|>=3.0.3,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']
openssl=1.1
pycparser=2.21 -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.5,<4.0a0|>=3.0.3,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']
python_abi=3.10 -> python=3.10 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.5,<4.0a0|>=3.0.3,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']

Package python conflicts for:
python=3.8
python_abi=3.10 -> python=3.10
cffi=1.15 -> python[version='3.8.12|3.9.10|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0',build='0_73_pypy|*_cpython|0_73_pypy']
pycparser=2.21 -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4']
cffi=1.15 -> pycparser -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4|3.10.*|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.11.*']

Package tzdata conflicts for:
pycparser=2.21 -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4'] -> tzdata
cffi=1.15 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
python_abi=3.10 -> python=3.10 -> tzdata

Package python_abi conflicts for:
cffi=1.15 -> python_abi[version='3.10.*|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.11.*|3.9|3.8',build='*_pypy39_pp73|*_cp311|*_cp310|*_cp39|*_cp38|*_pypy38_pp73']
python_abi=3.10

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 495, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 475, in execute
    outputs = api.build(
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 180, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 3097, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2126, in build
    create_build_envs(top_level_pkg, notest)
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1963, in create_build_envs
    build_actions = environ.get_install_actions(m.config.build_prefix,
  File "/Users/TESTUSER/miniconda3/envs/conda-build/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_build/environ.py", line 798, in get_install_actions
    raise DependencyNeedsBuildingError(exc, subdir=subdir)
conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform osx-arm64: {"zlib[version='>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']", "python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4|3.10.*|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.11.*']", 'tzdata', "python_abi[version='3.10.*|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.11.*|3.9|3.8',build='*_pypy39_pp73|*_cp311|*_cp310|*_cp39|*_cp38|*_pypy38_pp73']", "openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.5,<4.0a0|>=3.0.3,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']", 'pycparser', "zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']", "openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']", "python[version='2.7.*|>=3.4']", "openssl[version='>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1o,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.7,<4.0a0|>=3.0.5,<4.0a0|>=3.0.3,<4.0a0|>=3.0.2,<4.0a0|>=3.0.0,<4.0a0']", "python[version='3.8.12|3.9.10|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0',build='0_73_pypy|*_cpython|0_73_pypy']", 'python=3.10', 'ca-certificates'}
(conda-build) TESTUSER@TESTUSER-KPQ05P cryptography %
```

Comment: Why? Conda Forge already builds it. `conda install -c conda-forge cryptography=37.0.2` (see [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cryptography/files?version=37.0.2)). Note Conda Forge builds from the GitHub source rather than PyPI, since it also builds `cryptography-vectors` from the same repository. See [Conda Forge recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/cryptography-feedstock/blob/8b4f74d98a09e78f4ddb3e3f9449484bc09094e1/recipe/meta.yaml).

Answer (score 1):

The `python_abi` package version must be synced to Python version. So specifying `python=3.8` and `python_abi=3.10` will be unsolvable. Leaving off the `python_abi` version should be sufficient.

But please see my comment. This package is already available on Conda Forge, so there isn't much reason to be build it oneself. Also, the recipe OP proposes would strongly benefit from studying up on how the Conda Forge ones are done.

If one ever needs a specific build that is missing on Conda Forge, please post an Issue on the corresponding feedstock. In this case, [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/cryptography-feedstock/issues).

Comment: Thank you Merv, you defnintely pointed me in the right direction. python_abi was one problem, there are other dependencies that I still have to figure out - but going by your line of thought, I was able to build complete dependency tree from scratch and get to my final objective.